# Javascript split()

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
35 /obj/path objName 3.7k /obj/path/path objName 200m /objPath objName
```

Which I want to split like:

```
35 /obj/path objName

3.7k /obj/path/path objName

200m /objPath objName
```

I basically want to split from value to value and put them in a new array. I specifically have problems with how to approach it when it comes to the "." "m" or "k".

Edit:

My apologies, I tried regex within the split() method, but am not really good at it.

```
var str ="myExampleString";
var x = str.split(' ');
var text = "";

            function splitty() {
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    text += "<br>" + x[i];
                }
                return text;
```

Edit2: I wrote the wrong method in the title *fixed*.

Comment: `I specifically have problems with` - in what way? can't see your code, so as far as the question looks now it's like "can you do it all for me because I can't do anything"

Comment: check whether my answer suits your requirement

Answer (score 2):

I think the regex could be made more specific, but with the sample data given, this should work.

To explain the regex, it matches groups that consist of any number of digits or periods, then an optional m or k, then a space, then a string consisting of at least one non-space character, then a space, then a string consisting of at least one non-space character.

```js
var str = '35 /obj/path objName 3.7k /obj/path/path objName 200m /objPath objName';

var matches = str.match(/([\d\.]+[mk]? \S+ \S+)+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Tyvm, this does exactly what I need. I will play around with what you did to learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information you have provided, I recommend that you look into the `split()` function, using the space character as the separator. Something like this:

```
var string = "35 /obj/path objName 3.7k /obj/path/path objName 200m /objPath objName";
var tokens = string.split(" ");
```

Read more over the [MDN's split documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: OP wants to divide string based on integer values. 35, 3.7k, 200m

Comment: The snippet I wrote splits the string. OP just need to iterate through the resulting array of strings.

Comment: I edited my original post, to reflect how it is. It doesn't seem to split it right when I log it to html/console.

This is with split(' ');